# Why the += operator makes the difference in python while operating on strings like this

Tags: python

I came across a quiz and I found this question,and it made me wonder why the result is 879 for the following code

```
str1 = "87"
str1+= "0"
result = int(str1) + 9
print(result)
```

When I remove the part *str1+="0"* it gives the expected result 96 but I am still confused still as to why the second line of code is changing the output.

Comment: Take a look at the **In-place Operators** paragraph in https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the code is 879 because of the line str1 += "0", which appends "0" to the initial string "87", creating the string "870". Converting "870" to an integer and adding 9 results in 879. However, when you remove the str1 += "0" line, the string remains "87", and the final integer calculation becomes 87 + 9, giving the expected result of 96. The addition of the line str1 += "0" changes the string value, causing the difference in the final calculation and output.

Comment: Oh yes that was so simple. Thanks a lot. Sometimes solution is right in front of our eyes but we are too stiff I guess. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

It may help you to visualize it a little better with print statements:

```
str1 = "87"
print(str1)
str1 += "0"
print(str1)
result = int(str1) + 9
print(result)
```

Output:

```
87
870
879
```

The '+=' operator when applied to two strings will concatenate them together, meaning you end up with the string "870" when writing the statement "87" += "0".  The same applies when writing "87" += "1", your string become "871".

This is because Python does not look at these as numbers (ints) but as two strings, and that is the expected output of the += operator on two strings.

Comment: Yes that would've been a simpler approach to print every step. Back to basics.